# Adding Constraints to VARRAY UDT inside a Table in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm stuck figuring out how to add some constraints to the attributes of my UDTs.

Here's my situation. I've got a UDT that represents the daily number of hours an employee should work (forgive me for using Italian names).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TURNO_GIORNALIERO AS OBJECT(
    GIORNO   VARCHAR(15),
    ORA_INIZIO DATE,
    NUMERO_ORE  NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION getOreLavoro RETURN NUMBER
);
```

Then I defined new Type as a `VARRAY(5)` of `TURNO_GIORNALIERO`, named `TURNI_SETTIMANALI` (that is a Varray containing the number of hours an employee should work for each day of the week).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TURNI_SETTIMANALI AS VARRAY(5) OF TURNO_GIORNALIERO;
```

In the end, I've created the table that contains `TURNI_SETTIMANALI`.

```
CREATE TABLE TURNO_LAVORO(
    ID_TURNO CHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    TURNO   TURNI_SETTIMANALI NOT NULL,
);
```

What I want to do is to add a constraint to the table `TURNO_LAVORO` in order to check if `NUMERO_ORE` (defined in `TURNO GIORNALIERO`) is greater than 5.

Could someone please help me? I've tried several solutions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it is possible in `check` constraint. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204) says:

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following
>   constructs:
>
> - Calls to user-defined functions
> - Nested table columns or attributes

You could use trigger however. Test types and table:

```
create or replace type daily_cycle 
    as object(day varchar(15), hour_start date, hour_count number);
create or replace type week_cycle  
    as varray(5) of daily_cycle; 

create table test(id int, shift week_cycle);
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger hour_check before insert on test for each row
begin 
  for i in 1..:new.shift.count() loop
    if :new.shift(i).hour_count < 5 then 
      raise_application_error(-20001,'hours less than 5');
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

First `insert` works, second no:

```
insert into test values (1, 
    week_cycle(daily_cycle('a', date '2017-12-01',  5), 
               daily_cycle('b', date '2017-12-02',  8) ) );

insert into test values (2, 
    week_cycle(daily_cycle('a', date '2017-12-03',  3), 
               daily_cycle('b', date '2017-12-04', 12), 
               daily_cycle('b', date '2017-12-05',  7) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you @Ponder Stibbons, this worked perfectly. I thought I should have used a Trigger but wanted to ask to check if there was a better way.